# Vim Window in Tmux

Tags: tmux

In Tmux, how do I assign a particular program to a particular window, so that all  calls to that program from a shell in another window in Tmux will go to that program? One example would be a window that just keeps Vim open.

So in this example, whenever I type `vim myfile.txt` in my shell window in Tmux, I will see `myfile.txt` in the vim window of Tmux.

Answer (score 5):

There's no universal way to do this, since each program handles this differently, but vim has a client-server mode that might satisfy your needs in this particular instance.

Firstly, start vim in server mode:

```
vim --servername foo
```

Now you can open files in that instance of vim from elsewhere:

```
vim --servername foo --remote-tab file
```

This requires having a `vim` version compiled with `+clientserver`. On Debian, the `vim-gnome` package contains a version of vim with client-server functionality. Some other distributions have similar packages.